Change Level Values of an Image with a Python Script
I want to optimize my workflow as a texture artist. Preparing files to be used in other programs can take some time and can be automated since it is always the same. I used a self written python script to split the RGB channels, recombine them and export them into individual files and rename them (Alpha, Normal, Metall, AO etc.)
Now what i want to do is use a script to take the ALPHA channel of a .TIF file and change it's levels from 0, 1, 255 to 40, 1, 255 and export that Alpha as OriginalFilename_AO
I've attached two images from Photoshop doing this manually.
Original Alpha in Photoshop
Levels adjusted in Photoshop
And here is my code so far without the feature that i want to add. I tried some things but my output PNG for the Alpha / AO was always white so im doing something wrong. ;-)
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# Define input and output directories
input_folder = r"C:\Users\CmdNomad\Desktop\Import\MWimport\!input"
output_folder = r"C:\Users\CmdNomad\Desktop\Import\MWimport\!output"

def adjust_alpha_levels(alpha_channel, in_black, in_white, out_black, out_white):
    """
    Adjust levels of an image (alpha channel in this case).
    Maps pixel values from (in_black, in_white) to (out_black, out_white).
    """
    # Apply a point transform for remapping
    lut = [
        int(out_black + (pixel - in_black) * (out_white - out_black) / (in_white - in_black))
        if in_black <= pixel <= in_white else
        out_black if pixel < in_black else
        out_white
        for pixel in range(256)
    ]
    return alpha_channel.point(lut)

def extract_and_process_channels(input_folder, output_folder):
    # Ensure the output folder exists
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
    
    # Loop through all files in the input folder
    for file_name in os.listdir(input_folder):
        # Check if the file ends with MGC.tif
        if file_name.endswith("MGC.tif"):
            input_path = os.path.join(input_folder, file_name)
            
            try:
                # Open the TIFF image
                with Image.open(input_path) as img:
                    # Ensure the image is in RGB or RGBA mode
                    img = img.convert("RGBA")
                    
                    # Extract the red, green, and blue channels
                    red_channel = img.getchannel("R")
                    green_channel = img.getchannel("G")
                    blue_channel = img.getchannel("B")
                    
                    # Check for Alpha channel
                    alpha_channel = img.getchannel("A") if "A" in img.getbands() else None
                    
                    # Prepare the output file names
                    base_name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]  # Remove extension
                    metalness_file_name = f"{base_name}_Metalness.png"
                    roughness_file_name = f"{base_name}_Roughness.png"
                    alpha_file_name = f"{base_name}_Alpha.png"
                    ao_file_name = f"{base_name}_AO.png"
                    
                    # Define output paths
                    metalness_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, metalness_file_name)
                    roughness_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, roughness_file_name)
                    alpha_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, alpha_file_name)
                    ao_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, ao_file_name)
                    
                    # Save the red channel as Metalness PNG
                    red_channel.save(metalness_output_path)
                    print(f"Saved: {metalness_output_path}")
                    
                    # Save the green channel as Roughness PNG
                    green_channel.save(roughness_output_path)
                    print(f"Saved: {roughness_output_path}")
                    
                    # Save the blue channel as Alpha PNG
                    blue_channel.save(alpha_output_path)
                    print(f"Saved: {alpha_output_path}")
                    
                    # Adjust and save the alpha channel as AO PNG (if it exists)
                    if alpha_channel:
                        adjusted_alpha = adjust_alpha_levels(alpha_channel, 0, 255, 40, 255)
                        adjusted_alpha.save(ao_output_path)
                        print(f"Saved: {ao_output_path}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing {file_name}: {e}")

# Run the function
extract_and_process_channels(input_folder, output_folder)

I asked GPT but it's code for the feature did also only export a white image.
import os
from PIL import Image

# Define input and output directories
input_folder = r"C:\Users\CmdNomad\Desktop\ModernWarshipScripts\Import\MWimport\!input"
output_folder = r"C:\Users\CmdNomad\Desktop\ModernWarshipScripts\Import\MWimport\!output"

def adjust_alpha_levels(alpha_channel, in_black, in_mid, in_white, out_black, out_mid, out_white):
    """
    Adjust levels of an image (alpha channel in this case).
    Maps pixel values from (in_black, in_mid, in_white) to (out_black, out_mid, out_white).
    """
    lut = []
    for pixel in range(256):
        if pixel <= in_black:
            # Map below in_black to out_black
            lut.append(out_black)
        elif in_black < pixel <= in_mid:
            # Linear interpolation from (in_black -> in_mid) to (out_black -> out_mid)
            lut.append(
                int(out_black + (pixel - in_black) * (out_mid - out_black) / (in_mid - in_black))
            )
        elif in_mid < pixel <= in_white:
            # Linear interpolation from (in_mid -> in_white) to (out_mid -> out_white)
            lut.append(
                int(out_mid + (pixel - in_mid) * (out_white - out_mid) / (in_white - in_mid))
            )
        else:
            # Map above in_white to out_white
            lut.append(out_white)
    return alpha_channel.point(lut)

def extract_and_process_channels(input_folder, output_folder):
    # Ensure the output folder exists
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
    
    # Loop through all files in the input folder
    for file_name in os.listdir(input_folder):
        # Check if the file ends with MGC.tif
        if file_name.endswith("MGC.tif"):
            input_path = os.path.join(input_folder, file_name)
            
            try:
                # Open the TIFF image
                with Image.open(input_path) as img:
                    # Ensure the image is in RGBA mode
                    img = img.convert("RGBA")
                    
                    # Extract the red, green, and blue channels
                    red_channel = img.getchannel("R")
                    green_channel = img.getchannel("G")
                    blue_channel = img.getchannel("B")
                    
                    # Check for Alpha channel
                    alpha_channel = img.getchannel("A") if "A" in img.getbands() else None
                    
                    # Prepare the output file names
                    base_name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]  # Remove extension
                    metalness_file_name = f"{base_name}_Metalness.png"
                    roughness_file_name = f"{base_name}_Roughness.png"
                    alpha_file_name = f"{base_name}_Alpha.png"
                    ao_file_name = f"{base_name}_AO.png"
                    
                    # Define output paths
                    metalness_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, metalness_file_name)
                    roughness_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, roughness_file_name)
                    alpha_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, alpha_file_name)
                    ao_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, ao_file_name)
                    
                    # Save the red channel as Metalness PNG
                    red_channel.save(metalness_output_path)
                    print(f"Saved: {metalness_output_path}")
                    
                    # Save the green channel as Roughness PNG
                    green_channel.save(roughness_output_path)
                    print(f"Saved: {roughness_output_path}")
                    
                    # Save the blue channel as Alpha PNG
                    blue_channel.save(alpha_output_path)
                    print(f"Saved: {alpha_output_path}")
                    
                    # Adjust and save the alpha channel as AO PNG (if it exists)
                    if alpha_channel:
                        adjusted_alpha = adjust_alpha_levels(alpha_channel, 0, 1, 255, 40, 1, 255)
                        adjusted_alpha.save(ao_output_path)
                        print(f"Saved: {ao_output_path}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing {file_name}: {e}")

# Run the function
extract_and_process_channels(input_folder, output_folder)


Resulting image should look like in the Photoshp Picture above.
